# Help with a Pay-As-You-Go mobil/data plan for Europe

Tags: cellphones, data-plans

I will be stationed in Germany but will be traveling to Switzerland, Italy and Greece. Any ideas on a good plan that will allow me to use my iPhone for calls and data while traveling in Europe?

Comment: Which plans have you already looked at? What did and didn't you like about them? What more do you need? Only there are quite a few plans available, and no "best" one for everyone...

Comment: I have spent a good deal of time in the UK with 3 and their pre-paid plan is nice - especially with a "Feel at Home" add-on which allows for some travel in the EU. But now preparing to go to Germany I don't have any need to call back to the UK so I need something that will work well in Germany and around the EU. There are tons of websites that "advertise" these plans but would love a recommendation. So any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: How much data traffic? Especially data charges while roaming are still quite high within the EU. I know that Switzerland is not part of the EU, but at least some German mobile operators offer their EU tariffs in Switzerland as well.